# Many to Many on Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I have 3 tables to connect each other. Tables name's roles, role_user, and users. I want to make migration on laravel and adding some constraint. and here's what in my role tables migration:

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and here's my Users table migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and here's my role_user table migration:

```
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->unique(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

in my Migration order i put roles table on top of users already but i got this kind of errors:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `role_user` add constraint `role_user_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id
  `) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: If it is a many to many relationship your tables are right and the FK on `role_user` too, but why do you want to reference a role from your users object? That would be a one to one i guess?

Comment: hmm yeah i think u right, i was confuse about should i put roles_id or not. usually i use one to many but i change it. so you think i should put off my role_id in my users table?

Comment: Yes, remove that column from your users table. It has no use for your many to many relationship. (Also remove the foreign key ofcourse).

Comment: I do what u said and now i got this errors: 
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `role_user` add constraint `role_user_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id
  `) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: If i see the order of the FK being added, the FK for the users table goes well right? So maybe there is a problem with the Roles table? What is the order in which the migrations are ran?

Comment: first is roles table, and then users then role_user table.

Comment: what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the order of those tables being created. Check whether the `role_user` table is created at the end. Also, when you rollback, check if the constraints are dropped as well. More references [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations).

Comment: Keep in mind that newer versions of Laravel use big integers for default id 's.

Comment: you may have to be using biginteger in modern laravel apps.

Answer (score 6):

Probably your problem was with the order of creation of migrations.

Laravel runs the migrations in order of creation using the timestamp in the file name , because of that, if you created them in the following order:

1. roles in `2018_06_02_023539_create_roles_table`
2. role_user in `2018_06_02_023800_create_role_user_table`
3. users in `2018_06_02_023815_create_users_table`

The table `users` would not exist when referenced in the table `role_user`, thus causing an SQL error.
The most simple fix that you could do is renaming the `role_user` migration file in this way:

`2018_06_02_023800_create_role_user_table` => `2018_06_02_023820_create_role_user_table`

Answer (score 4):

Try this one on the pivot table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in table "role_user" replace columns  type from integer to bigIncrements

Comment: Be Careful: Laravel 5.8 Added bigIncrements As Defaults https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/

Answer (score -1):

I delete all my table and left just 4 tables :

```
create_user_table,
create_password_reset, 
create_roles_table, 
create_role_user
```

and everything works fine.

Till now I don't understand what makes these errors although I already put the same orders.